# What should I do if text is not output from html5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

```
<script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    function numText(num,x,y) 
    {
    this.num = num,
    this.x = x,
    this.y = y;
    }

    numText.prototype.writeText = function()
    {
    context.font ='60px Bahnschrift SemiCondensed';
    context.fillStyle = 'red';
    context.fillText(numText.text,numText.x,numText.y);
    }

    var text1 = new numText("30",100,225);
    text1.writeText();
</script>
```

I want to print out the "30" using the concept of object-oriented programming.
What should I do if the text is not printed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to correct two things:

- replace the reference to `numText` with `this` in the `writeText` function.
   When you call that function, you do it in the context of a specific instance and to reference its properties the `this` keyword is used
- when calling `context.fillText` you are using property `text` instead of `num` as the first argument

Corrected code:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');

function numText(num, x, y) {
    this.num = num,
        this.x = x,
        this.y = y;
}

numText.prototype.writeText = function () {
    context.font = '60px Bahnschrift SemiCondensed';
    context.fillStyle = 'red';
    context.fillText(this.num, this.x, this.y);
}

var text1 = new numText("30", 100, 225);
text1.writeText();
```